# AngularStrap typeahead, how to use event callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using an AngularStrap typeahead and need a callback, when an items gets selected by the user. According to the [documentation](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads-usage), there is an `onSelect` option, which can be supplied with a `function`, and:

> If provided, this function will be invoked when an item is selected.

… and …

> Options can be passed via data-attributes on the directive or as an object hash to configure the service. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-animation="".

So I tried using it as follows:

```
<input type="text" 
       class="form-control" 
       ng-model="selection" 
       bs-options="item for item in items" 
       bs-typeahead 
       data-on-select="onSelect">
```

And provide the `onSelect()` method within my controller:

```
$scope.onSelect = function() {
    console.log('this never gets called :(');
};
```

However, the callback is never invoked. Anything I'm missing here?

---

**[edit]** dfsq pointed out that it should be `bs-on-select`, regarding to the library’s sources. I just tried this variant, however the event only gets triggered once. I created [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5gz8gcKO2ZxNIbqNZWYx) to illustrate my issue; the "Number of selection events" should naturally be incremented with each selection, however it remains 1.

Comment: you ve to pass the name of the function not a call to that function.... use "onSelect"

Comment: Have you tried `data-on-select="onSelect"`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a stupidity when putting together the example. The actual example was 'correct' in that regard, and still does **not** work. Fixing the post.

Comment: In your plunker if you use bs-on-select="onSelect" it works

Comment: @Vanojx1 Wow, thanks!!! Now I feel a bit stupid ... I also should have tried this, but at the end I obviously didn't see the forest for the trees :) Thank you so much for your patience and pointing this out. Feel free to post this as an answer and I will gladly accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this was answered in the comments by [@Vanojx1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3480602/vanojx1) and that it should be:

```
bs-on-select="onSelect"
```

I've updated the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSnWIS4rgPlYlCIPPcDz?p=info) with this change and it works (however, it doesn't call the method until the input loses focus).